# "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets" when trying to set a custom eval_metric using LGBMClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, lightgbm

My y going in and both `y_train` and `y_eval` are binary int, what am I doing wrong?

I noticed the predictions going out are like this `[0.,1.,0. ...]` which is probably the culprit of the problem; but I'm not sure what is causing it.

```
lgbm_clf = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(
    objective="binary",
    random_state=1,
    n_estimators=10000,
    boosting="gbdt",
    is_unbalance = True,
    metric= None)

lgbm_clf.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_eval, y_eval)],
        eval_metric=evalerror,
        early_stopping_rounds=150)
    
preds = lgbm_clf.predict(X_eval)
print(f"LightGBM AUC on the evaluation set: {roc_auc_score(y_eval, preds):.5f}")
```

my custom metric is:

```
def evalerror(preds, y_eval):
  tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_eval, preds).ravel()
  return 'credimiMetric',((3*tp - (3*fp) - (50*fn))*1000), True
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error when fitting?

```
Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback, and ideally a small dataset that reproduces your issue.

Comment: As far as I remember `press` are probabilities and not classes - you need to convert them into classes using some threshold.